# Match multiple user-agents in robots.txt with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, robots.txt

I am new to Scrapy and I would like to know how to make the spider obey the rules of two or more User-agents in the robots.txt file (for instance, Googlebot and Googlebot-Mobile).

I am currently using `ROBOTSTXT_USER_AGENT` but that option only lets me specify a single user agent string to use for matching in the robots.txt file, and I need to match at least two user agents. Do you know any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I just used `/` to separate the users agents to match and it worked:

```
"ROBOTSTXT_USER_AGENT": "Googlebot | Googlebot-Mobile | *"
```